# Setting the value of a column in SQL Server based on the scope_identity() of the insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in a program that is not performing well. Its truncated version follows. The `MyQuotes` table has an `IDENTITY` column called `QuoteId`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertQuote 
    (@BinderNumber VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
     @OtherValue VARCHAR(50))
AS
    INSERT INTO MyQuotes (BinderNumber, OtherValue) 
    VALUES (@BinderNumber, @OtherValue);

    DECLARE @QuoteId INT 
    SELECT @QuoteId = CONVERT(INT, SCOPE_IDENTITY());

    IF @BinderNumber IS NULL 
        UPDATE MyQuotes 
        SET BinderNumber = 'ABC' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@QuoteId)
        WHERE QuoteId = @QuoteId;

        SELECT @QuoteId AS QuoteId;
```

I feel like the section where we derive the binder number from the `scope_identity()` can be done much, much, cleaner. And I kind of think we should have been doing this in the C# code rather than the SQL, but since that die is cast, I wanted to fish for more learned opinions than my own on how you would change this query to populate that value.

Comment: Aside: Since there is an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions) from `numeric` to `int` you could simply use `declare @QuoteId as Int = Scope_Identity();`.

Comment: As @SMor comments below, is it ever possible for a BinderNumber to be set to `null` at a later point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The following update avoids needing the id:

```
    UPDATE MyQuotes SET
      BinderNumber = 'ABC' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), QuoteId)
    WHERE BinderNumber is null;
```

2. If selecting QuoteId as a return query is required then using `scope_identity()` is as good a way as any.

Comment: And that update is not logically the same as the original query. You assume that BinderNumber cannot be set to NULL at any point after insertion. OP did not make any such claim. Therefore this update can set **any number of rows** to have a new binder number.

Comment: @SMor You're right, there is the possibility of null being valid for BinderNumber, one of many things the OP needs to clarify. But this update **will always** generate a unique BinderNumber for all rows updated, because its using the id of the row which is an identity field.

Answer (score 1):

Dale's answer is better, however this can be useful way too:

```
DECLARE @Output TABLE (ID INT);
INSERT INTO MyQuotes (BinderNumber, OtherValue) VALUES (@BinderNumber, @OtherValue)  OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @Output (ID);
UPDATE q SET q.BinderNumber = 'ABC' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),o.ID)
FROM MyQuotes q
INNER JOIN @Output o ON o.ID = q.ID
;
```

Also, if BinderNumber is always linked to ID, it would be better to just create computed column

```
AS 'ABC' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ID)
```

Comment: I nearly suggested the computed column - but then realised that the SP can take that in as a parameter - so this is only inserting a default value - I think :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Could be.